# ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, module, installation, tensorflow, pip

Please help me with this error

I have installed the tensorflow module on my server and below is it's information

```
15IT60R19@cpusrv-gpu-109:~$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/other/15IT60R19/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: mock, numpy, protobuf, wheel, six
```

But when I try to import tensorflow I get following error

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

My python version is as following

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
```

I have tried the solutions given in 
[sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472144/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-cant-install-tensorflow)

[Sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658793/tensorflow-installation-issuesimporterror-no-module-named-tensorflow)

I do not have sudo access to the server 
I can only use pip to install any module

Answer (score 56):

Try installing tensorflow again with the whatever version you want and with option --ignore-installed like:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.2.0 --ignore-installed
```

I solved same issue using this command.

Comment: I tried it and it yielded `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

Comment: I think you can try newer versions then. You can uninstall the previous one and do fresh install instead.

Comment: I had the same issue and it got resolved with this
`pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed --user`

Comment: I use @AmoghMishra's method and add the path in the environmental variables and it works!

Answer (score 34):

I had a more basic problem when I received this error.

The "Validate your installation" instructions say to type: **python**

However, I have both 2.7 and 3.6 installed.  Because I used **pip3** to install tensorflow, I needed to type: **python3**

Using the correct version, I could import the "tensorflow" module.

Answer (score 31):

Check if Tensorflow was installed successfully using:

```
 pip3 show tensorflow
```

If you get something like

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.2.1
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: bleach, markdown, html5lib, backports.weakref, werkzeug, numpy, protobuf, wheel, six
```

You may try adding the path of your tensorflow location by:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/your/tensorflow/path:$PYTHONPATH.
```

Comment: Adding the path can be help for me.

Answer (score 28):

For Anaconda3, simply install in Anaconda Navigator:
[image]

Comment: Installation of tensorflow works perfectly with Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: It still says `ImportError: No module named tensorflow`

Answer (score 12):

Try installing tensorflow in the user site - This installation only works for you.

> pip install tensorflow --user

Answer (score 10):

You may need this since first one may not work.

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 10):

you might wanna try this:

```
$conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Comment: This did it for me on Python 3.6

Answer (score 6):

For me, if I did

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

then I got the error the OP reports when using a 3rd party library calling tensorflow.

However, when I substituted either `tensorflow-cpu` or `tensorflow-gpu` (depending upon which one is appropriate for you) then the code was suddenly able to find tensorflow.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to install tensorflow GPU for a Windows 7 with pip3 for python3.5.x. 
Instead of doing `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` I just did `pip install tensorflow` and after it completed i was finally able to import tensorflow in python3.5.x.

Answer (score 4):

**with python2**

`pip show tensorflow`  to check install

`python test.py`  to run test

**with python3**

`pip3 show tensorflow` to check install

`python3 test.py` to run test

**test.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[3.,4], [5.,6], [6.,7]])
step = tf.reduce_mean(c, 1)                                                                                 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(step))
```

Or, if you haven't install tensorflow yet, try the [offical document](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/#anaconda_installation)

Comment: I see the same error. pip3 show tensorflow does show the installed version of tensor flow, but when i try to import tensorflow within python3 console, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'"

Answer (score 2):

So, your problem is that you are using the wrong commands.
If you install it with `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`, then it will install for **Python3**. Not any other types like py, or python.

Your solution: Run these commands:

1. `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`
2. `python -m pip install tensorflow`
3. `py -m pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the doc's command (`conda create -n tensorflow pip python=2.7 # or python=3.3, etc.`) which wanted to install python2.7 in the conda environment, and kept erroring out saying the module can't be found when following the installation validation steps, I used `conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3` to make sure python3 was installed in the environment.

Doing this, I only had to type `python` instead of `python3` when validating the installation and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all underscores in the jupyter notebook file name, it should start working. No idea why.

For example, test.ipynb could import tensorflow, but test_test.ipynb couldn't.

If you're like me, you created a jupyter notebook file (.ipynb) and couldn't import tensorflow even though it installed properly.

This problem didn't occur with normal python files (.py), regardless of whether they had underscores in their names or not.

I'm using vscode if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Anaconda install steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation) from TensorFlow docs.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the virtualenv environment by issuing one of the following commands:

$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate # bash, sh, ksh, or zsh
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate.csh  # csh or tcsh

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade six
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
It's because default python is in version 2
You need to link to the version 3.

```
>sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python
>sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
```

[image: python links]

Comment: Just use `pip3 install` instead of `pip install`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I simply updated my command to begin with `python3` instead of `python` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I install `32 Bit Python` so I cannot install Tensorflow, After uninstall `32 Bit Python` and install `64 Bit Python`, I can install tensorflow successfully.

After reinstall `Python 64 bit`, you need to check your python install folder path is properly set in Windows Environment Path.

You can check Python version by typing `python` in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

On my remote machine, I had `TensorFlow` installed via `pip` and when I was importing it in `ipython` the import was successful. Despite of that I still got the `No module named tensorflow` error when I was running my scripts. The issue here was that I was running my scripts with `sudo`, so the `python` and `tensorflow` paths were not visible to the root. When I ran my scripts without `sudo`, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

My experience.

A, check your python version, in my case python 3.6

B, use the command: python3.6 myscript.py;

C, my tensorflow version is 1.10

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late answer, but I guess might be a common one. I had encountered the same problem and neither of the proposed methods in here worked for my case, **Python v3.7** and working on a **Linux** server. I tested the following command line and it worked for me:

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

More details here: https://appuals.com/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-for-tensorflow/

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Unable to edit a similar solution up there