# ImportError:libcudart.so.8.0:cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow

I used the spyder or terminal to run the mnist_deep.py program ,  it can run normally, but when i run the program using pycharm, it will cause an error.The Project Interpreter is 2.7.12(~/anaconda2/bin/python).
Error Type: 
ImportError:libcudart.so.8.0:cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory
Error importing tensorflow.Unless you are using bazel,you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;please exit the tensorflow source tree,and relaunch your python interpreter from there

Comment: Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

It's preferable to do a system-wide configuration instead of editing `~/.bashrc`. Create a .conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`:

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf`

Add this:

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib  # you probably don't need this line; check
                         # if the directory exists
```

Then run `sudo ldconfig`. Hope this brings you joy.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this since months. Thanks a lot for this.  
And yes, starting from cuda-8.0 and above, you might not require the second line.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had installed `tensorflow-gpu` on a machine without a GPU.
Uninstalling it fixed the problem

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed
```

Without the 2nd step, I was getting an error `No module named tensorflow` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551934/4126114))