# Python cannot find Tensorflow module

Tags: tensorflow, pip, gpu, python-3.5

With Python3.5, I try to use the 'tensorflow' module:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

But.. it says `No mudule named tensorflow`

I just tried to download the module with pip3:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

(I have all the requirements to run tensorflow with GPU support as described at tensorflow.org)

Comment: What was the output of "pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu" when you ran it?

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons

"Successfuly installed absl-py-0.4.1 astor-0.7.1 gast-0.2.0 grpcio-1.14.2 markdown-2.6.11 numpy-1.14.5 protobuf-3.6.1 six-1.11.0 tensorboard-1.10.0 tensorflow-gpu-1.10.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.14.1 wheel-0.31.1"

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a similar question here [ImportError: No module named tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow) , here's a sum up of what's inside:

1. Make sure installation is correct via:
   `pip3 show tensorflow`
2. You can optionally re-install it again using: `pip install tensorflow==1.2.0 --ignore-installed`
3. Make sure you're running the python code with Python 3.x, verify using: `python --version`
4. Make sure you install TF and run the script through the same user, avoid installing TF using `sudo pip install...` and running the code with `python script.py`

Comment: I did the following:
pip install tensorflow==1.5.0 --ignore-installed

Well... now it's working. But how can I know it runs on GPU and not on CPU?

Comment: I've never done that before, however .. This question is very promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell

Comment: @TalRofe Enabling log and check your terminal

Comment: As I'm following "Sheraz" answer (from the link u gave), I only get CPU message. Not GPU...

Comment: I don't have much experience with using GPU actually .. But a quick guess, wouldn't that mean that it's not using the GPU??