# When I import tensor flow it says no module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

(Beginner)

I followed all of the instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip to install tensor flow 2 on my Mac with anaconda. I am new to computers and before I tried this method, I attempted several other ways, none of which worked. The problem I have is when I attempt to import tensorflow, it says no module named tensorflow found.

I'm not sure it makes a difference but I figured I should include that when I followed the steps provided on the tensorflow website, it would't work on the Mac terminal so I used the terminal provided in vs code.

Comment: It can be a problem in the path, see this question for clarifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

try: `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow

You're using anaconda to manage your packages. I'd therefore try to avoid pip as they may cause issues when used in tandem

Comment: should I do this in the virtual environment

Comment: Yes - in the virtual environment