# No module named "tensorflow"

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I want to build tensorflow with python libraries. Currently I have tensorflow installed but I do not see python packages in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` so when I try to import tensorflow module in python terminal, it fails. However, there is library in `/usr/lib` and C++ programs work.
What is flag/target needed in bazel build?

Comment: Try this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow) link. Maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can get TensorFlow in python package by:

1. Directly doing pip install tensorflow: It will install the precompiled version by directly downloading a wheel file.
2. Build from source code in GitHub using bazel build.

For the second approach, the following steps are needed:

1. Take the source code from GitHub.
2. Compile the code using bazel build. It will give the ".whl" file.
3. Do pip install /tmp/TensorFlow-version-tags.whl

For detailed installation, steps follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).