# Tensorflow can’t be import after lib installation

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am using Tensorflow docker.
Inside docker  matplotlib is installed using `apt-get install python-matplotlib`. After installation tensorflow can't be imported. Before installation was ok.

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
>>>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow

Have you tried these solutions?

Comment: @burntchowmein before matplotlib is installed, tensorflow was in docker.