# My pip died after I tried add path to PATH

Tags: python, pip

I had a pip that worked ok, but then I did:

PATH=$PATH:C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts

to fix the tensorflow import problem [ImportError: No module named tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow)

and after that pip is no longer recognized, when I type:

pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed --user

It response by:

'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

How I fix it back?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, variables (including environment variables) are expanded with % sign like %PATH%, not like $PATH. In addition to this, path separator is a semicolon `;`, not colon `:` ([source 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993), [source 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa922003(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

So to set it properly, you'd have to set it to

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It didn't helped, the pip still dont recognized

Comment: I closed and opend my cmd and now it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Yep, was just about to tell that setting PATH in command line affects just current session.

Answer (score 0):

Check Python and pip is in PATH using command: "`where python`" or "`where pip`"

You can set PATH as "`set PATH=C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;%PATH%`"
Now on success of the above steps, proceed with installation of tensorflow.
"`pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed --user`"
or
"`python -m pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed --user`"